# A name for a numerical phenomena when using numerical methods

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-equations, iterative-method, convergence, terminology

I have a nonlinear solver for equation
$$g= c_1f(x_1,y_1)+c_2f(x_2,y_2)$$

Note that $c_1$ is much bigger than $c_2$. After using [Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm), it seemed to only optimize $x_1$ and $y_1$, while $c_2f(x_2,y_2)$ is ignored by the solver.

Is there a proper noun for this phenomenon?

Comment: Scaling problem.

Comment: This might be the answer I've been looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Verbs for ways to solve scaling problems include things like 'normalizing', 'rescaling' (obviously) or, sometimes, 'non-dimensionalizing'

Comment: If you're running into issues like this, I recommend looking at Deuflhard's [Newton Methods for Nonlinear Problems](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-23899-4). He talks a lot about algorithms that have invariance properties w.r.t. scaling or other linear transformation, which is likely to help with your problem.

Comment: @DanielShapero this book is indeed a goldmine, however I think it rather deals with scaling of the variables, not of the various functions which may be summed in the objective function (or residual function).

Answer (score 3):

You could call this a "scaling" problem. Your $c$ variables essential form the weights on a [multi-objective optimization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-objective_optimization). If $c_1\gg c_2$, then the objective associated with $c_1$ becomes, essentially, the only thing that matters.

You have a few options for dealing with this:

- decrease $c_1$
- increase $c_2$
- Use a more aggressive form of $f(x_2,y_2)$. For instance, choosing $\left(f(x_2,y_2)\right)^2$ will greatly exaggerate $f(x_2,y_2)$ which may cause your solver to pay more attention to it. However, once $f(x_2,y_2)$ is brought low enough, the $c$ weights will become more important again.

You could also try to extract the [Pareto frontier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_front), the set of solutions where an improvement in the $c_1$ objective would cause a loss in the $c_2$ objective, and vice versa. You can get this by choosing a bunch of $c$ values and taking a convex hull or by slowly decreasing $c_1$ while increasing $c_2$.

Note that this kind of problem shows up in [ridge regression](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/tutorial-ridge-lasso-elastic-net) and [Lasso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)), and more generally as part of [regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)), where the objective functions take the form of
$$
\lVert y-X\beta\rVert^2 + \lambda\lVert \beta \rVert^2\text{   (Ridge)}
$$
and
$$
\lVert y-X\beta\rVert^2 + \lambda\lVert \beta \rVert_1\text{   (Lasso)}
$$
So looking into [how that parameter is chosen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)#Choice_of_regularization_parameter) might also be useful.

Comment: Perhaps you have an extra square $^2$ in Lasso?

Comment: Multi-Objective optimisation (e.g. MGDA) can also be of interest maybe !